AD account not unlocking
I have found that when an account is locked according to the AD password policy, it is never unlocked per the policy.
The Group Policy has the Account Lockout duration set to five minutes. The other settings of the Account Lockout Policy work, the lockout duration does not.
I have used Group Policy Results to verify the correct settings. Using the "Account Lockout Status" program I can see there are no continuing login attempts.
I have done research but not finding anything about this.
TEST PASSWORD POLICY
Account Lockout Status
Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy screenshot

GP Results won't verify anything for you when you have fine-grained password policies. You need to check the results of Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy.  Also, you haven't included a screenshot of the Default Domain Policy for comparison with the salestest policy.

And, completely unsolicited.  45 day password rotation is awful.

Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy shows the correct expected information Screen shot added

Ah.  I think I see what's going on, the accounts password is expired, as such I think it won't auto unlock.

The test account's password is expired according to the policy configured. Update the password so it satisfies the 45 day maximum, and then try the lockout timer again.

Not in this case. This particular account is set for the password to never expire. Additionally, to "test" your assumption of the problem. I removed the "password does not expire" check, reset the password and unlocked the account, and tested again. Account did not unlock. Your assumption has been proven false.
